# Pass Windows Identity through Client Server framework to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a corporate client server application. It passes majority of the work from the client application (Windows 7) to the server application (Server 2008 R2), and when it comes to running a SQL query (SQL Server 2008), it is handled by the server - which registers the user as the server.

We then have a table in our database which is locked down using Active Directory. 
Our client and server are written in .Net 4.0. I'm Using WCF (net.tcp).

How would I pass the logged in user security token from our Windows 7 client, to our server in order for the server to turn around and use it to connect to the SQL server to run a couple of quick queries.

Any thoughts, or ideas, would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a service account for SQL server access.

You can impersonate/change identity in your windows application using the service account before making a call to database. so while database call is being executed it will run under impersonated identity(service account).  For impersonation in windows application [see this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is the double hop scenario.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334665/steps-to-enable-double-hop-delegation-in-iis7-windows-2008) SO question regarding how to set up double hop possibilities.