# Understanding Asp.net, IIS, and Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, active-directory

Can anyone explain to me how active directory works with IIS?  I have an ASP.net application that looks up folders on a server and lists out all sub folders.  It's a tree view with nodes.  WHen the user clicks the node, it does a postback to get the child folders and appends them to the tree view.  Within the various folders there are shortcuts to shared folders on remote servers, like this:

```
\\myServer\somefolder\anotherFolder\shortcutToRemoteFolder\aThirdFolder\aFourthFOlder
```

My application uses windows authentication and active directory.  When the user starts my app, we get their domain\userid.  If i try to directly to:

```
\\myServer\somefolder\anotherFolder\shortcutToRemoteFolder\aThirdFolder
```

I get an error:

> The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account
>   or local user account to access this server.

But, if I work my way Up the chain of folders, like this:

```
  \\myServer\somefolder\
  \\myServer\somefolder\anotherFolder\
  \\myServer\somefolder\anotherFolder\shortcutToRemoteFolder\
  \\myServer\somefolder\anotherFolder\shortcutToRemoteFolder\aThirdFolder
```

It's fine.  Are permissions not being propagated through to the remover server?  Does the IIS account change?  Any insight would be great.

Comment: Does the remote server "\\myServer" have SharePoint on it (for file-shares) or just ordinary NT Shared folders or maybe a NAS?

Comment: What user account does the ASP.net application run as?  Is the ASP.net application running on myServer, or a different server?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, IIS will not leverage the (connected client's) domain account credentials to connect to another server.  This is commonly known as the "IIS double hop" scenario.  There are ways to get around it using kerberos or allowing impersonation on your server, but each of these approaches has limits (due to the very serious consequences of allowing this kind of thing).  You could read this SO posting: [Steps to enable double-hop delegation in IIS7 windows 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334665/steps-to-enable-double-hop-delegation-in-iis7-windows-2008) or just do a web search on "IIS double hop".

Comment: At first, I thought I might understand, but I don't think that I do lol.  I can see the issue with the IIS Double Hop and security.  But, why can't I use the full path to go directly to the server but I can incrementally get there?  Shouldn't I get an error regardless?

Comment: Aah yes.  I didn't understand your question until now.  Yes, that is very strange that the remote connection works at all.