# Kerberos Authentication implementation in ASP.NET MVC 5(not core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, kerberos

I am not able to find any proper resources which can show how to implement kerberos authentication using ASP.NET MVC. The resources which I am getting are either partly coded or is mainly based on core. As I am new to this Kerberos authentication I don't know where to start and how can I implement it in my ASP.NET application. Please help me on this.
P.S: I do have a code in java which implements this kerberos authentication using spring in my client machine but I dont have any idea how to convert it into ASP.NET MVC code.

I have tried this [Asp.net and Kerberos Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330006/asp-net-and-kerberos-authentication) link but it is quite outdated. And I dont have idea how to use SPN, Keytabs etc. in my ASP.NET application.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-windows-authentication-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: This is for windows authentication but I need code for kerberos authentication and how to implement keytabs and spn in the asp.net application?

Comment: "Windows Authentication (also known as Negotiate, Kerberos, or NTLM authentication)" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: As I have already told in the heading, I need code for ASP.Net MVC (.Net Framework) and not core and can you please suggest the nuget packages which I can use it in my MVC application again not CORE.

Comment: the link in the first comment

Comment: That link you put in your question is still accurate and still the way to do it. IIS does the Windows Authentication for you. If your server is on the same AD domain as the users, then you should be able to put `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your web.config and it'll just work. In your ASP.NET code you can get the user in `HttpContext.Current.User`

Comment: @GabrielLuci So do I have to modify anything on code level or I need to change in the IIS level only for Kerberos Authentication.

Comment: At minimum you need to update your web.config so IIS does the authentication. If you want your application to be aware of who is logged in, then you need to change your code.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Your professionalism and knowledge in this subject area never cease to amaze me.  @ Akash pal - Is it working now?