# setting up double hop authentication to File Server,getting 401 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, kerberos

I have followed many [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334665/steps-to-enable-double-hop-delegation-in-iis7-windows-2008#4336423) on this but none of it is helping

the flow is like this

- www.example.com  ->Windows Authentication,IIS7,ApplicationPoolIdentity
- content is all static contents from //UNCshare
- Enabled Delegation on machine account

I can access the site locally by using http://localhost. But when i access from another machine or the hostname,it keeps prompting 3 times and fails.

Comment: Take a WireShark trace of the traffic during the failure scenario and identify the relevant authentication protocol streams in play and report back to us here.  Even can take a screenshot of it and post it.  Then we can suggest the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had duplicate SPN for this server machine and because of that kerberos was failing. Double hop requires kerberos. This command helped me.

`setspn -x`

More details can be found  in this [msdn forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/09a86d74-de48-4bda-9cc9-435da4f59910/remove-duplicate-spn?forum=winservergen)